# How to do a particular JQUERY text animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css-animations

I am trying to improve my web skills whenever I come across something cool. Recently I came across this CSS text animation where the word is typed erased and a new word is type. The links are below:

1. https://www.betterment.com/
2. https://www.veritas.com

I also tried to copy it from https://jsfiddle.net/krs8785/jdfgo5on/, but how do I get the animation effect?

Ref - https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-animated-headlines

```html
<div class="inner">
    <h2 class="animated-headline" data-delay=2000>A investment service built for
        <br>
        <span class="animation fifth">unpredictable markets.</span>
        <span class="typed-cursor">|</span>
        <span class="headline-partial">retiring comfortably.</span>
        <span class="headline-partial">lowering fees.</span>
        <span class="headline-partial">dreaming big.</span>
    </h2>
    
</div>
<style>
    .inner .animated-headline .animation,
    .inner .animated-headline .animation.first {
        color: #90caf9
    }
    .inner .animated-headline .animation.second {
        color: #7fb800
    }
    .inner .animated-headline .animation.third {
        color: #ffb400
    }
    .inner .animated-headline .animation.fourth {
        color: #90caf9
    }
    .inner .animated-headline .animation.fifth {
        color: #7fb800
    }
   .inner .animated-headline .headline-partial {
       display: none
   }

   @keyframes blink {
       0%, 100% {
           opacity: 1
       }
       50% {
           opacity: 0
       } 
   }

   .inner .animated-headline .typed-cursor {
       color: #999;
       font-weight: 300;
       opacity: 1;
       animation: blink .7s infinite;
       display: inline-block
   }
</style>
```

Comment: It's not a CSS-animation, it's a jQuery animation.

Comment: any tips on how to do ?

Comment: Chk this link : http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css

Check these fiddles

https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/x8obp5ew/

http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/mcjbt5em/

```
h1 { 
    font-size:150%;
    width:16.3em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right: .1em solid black;

    -webkit-animation: typing 10s steps(30, end), /* # of steps = # of characters */
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: typing 10s steps(30, end), /* # of steps = # of characters */
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
}
```